# Cannot render objects of this.props.location.state in UI reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017, react-router-v4

I am very new to react and developing an app using react in visual studio 2017 where a user enters some name in a textbox and below it a list appears giving him suggestions. When the user clicks on any item, he is redirected to another page where more properties of the suggested item are shown. So far i have passed the state of one component to another using Link but cannot display the properties of that state in another component. Below is the typescript code of my components.

Search.tsx:

```
class Users {
profileId: string;
firstName: string;
middleName: string;
lastName: string;
dateOfBirth: string;
}

class Data {
users: Users[];
}

class QueryDetails {
search: string;
returncount: number;
skip: number;
top: number;
}

class SearchResult {
queryDetails: QueryDetails;
data: Data;
}  

class SearhProps {
searchResult: SearchResult;
searchText: string;
}


export class Search extends React.Component<any, SearhProps> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { searchText: '', searchResult: new SearchResult };
    this.handleSearchTextChange = this.handleSearchTextChange.bind(this);
}

public render() {
    return <div>
        <div>
            <input value={this.state.searchText} onChange={this.handleSearchTextChange} type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.searchResult.data ? this.state.searchResult.data.users.map((user, index) =>
                    <li key={index}>
                        <Link to={{ pathname: '/s', search: '?name=' + this.state.searchText, state: this.state.searchResult.data }} key={index}>
                            <span>{user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName}</span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ) : null}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>;
}
```

On handleSearchTextChange method i hit an api endpoint and get all the information of the user entered in the textbox and show only the required fields i.e. first name and last name in the suggestion list.

Now as all the information is in this.state.searchResult.data i want to pass this to another component which has route '/s'. This component is as below:-

SearchLanding.tsx:

```
class Users {
profileId: string;
firstName: string;
middleName: string;
lastName: string;
dateOfBirth: string;
}

class UsersList {
users: Users[]
}

export class SearchLanding extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>  {
constructor() {
    super();
}

public render() {
return <div>
const userList = this.props.location.state as UsersList; //<= Logging userList or this.props.location.state gives me {users: Array(3)} and i get all the info if i expand this array
//This div will contain blocks of div which will show all the information of the user. But for now i am trying to display only the first name of the user
{userList ? userList.users.map(e => {
                <h2>{e.firstName}</h2>
            }) : null} //<= This is where it is not working
<div>
```

can somebody tell me where i am going wrong? I get the necessary objects in this.props.location.state but cant seem to display it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the braces around `<h2>{e.firstName}</h2>` in the `map` callback. Either remove them, or use `{return <h2>{e.firstName}</h2>}` as otherwise the result of `map` is an array of `undefined`s. There's a couple more syntax problems in `render`, but I assume those are from partially copy/pasting the code.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved :) But i cant seem to undestand that why this piece of code works in Search component and not SearchLanding component. The old code also displayed list of items.  I just wrote return and it started displaying the headers

Comment: There are no braces in the right-hand side of the arrow function in `Search.tsx`. If you use braces, you need to `return` a value. If you don't use braces, the entire right-hand side expression is taken to be the return value (ie. `x => 42` means `x => {return 42;}`).